# How do I add two same size binary arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, binary, addition

In this function, the parameters `first_complement2` and `second_complement2` are 2 arrays that contain binary digits of the 2 2’s complement numbers. Assume that the two given 2’s complement numbers have same size. The function returns an int array that contains binary digits of the addition result of the 2 given 2’s complement numbers with same size.

```
int* complement2_add(int first_complement2[], int* second_complement2[], int size)
{
    int i;
    int carry = 0;
    int result_array = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    for(i = size-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        result_array[i] = (first_complement2[i] + second_complement2[i] + carry) %2; //it says "Invalid operands to binary % (have 'int *' and int)"
        carry = (first_complement2[i] + second_complement2[i] + carry)/2 ; //as well as "Invalid operands to binary / (have 'int *' and int)"
    }

    result_array[i] = carry; // and here "subscripted value is neither an array nor pointer nor vector
    int j;

    for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", result_array[j]);
    }
    return result_array;
}
```

Comment: What are binary arrays ?

Comment: the binary arrays are int, the can be any size but both are the same size and have binary values in them

Comment: they are regular arrrays but only have binary values is all so im trying to do binary addition with these arrays

Comment: Side note: don't cast `malloc` in C.

Comment: `second_complement2[i]` is an `int *`. don't know if this is a typo, mistake, or intended, but you need to either derefernce that or index it (if an array) to add the integer value to `first_complement2[i]` and `carry`.

Comment: Turn up your compiler-warnings to near-max levels. There are at least two issues in this code that any modern compiler would flag.

Comment: yea the second parameter was a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

First, your function declaration is incorrect.  `second_complement2` is an array, so it should be declared as `int []` or `int *`:

```
int* complement2_add(int first_complement2[], int second_complement2[], int size)
```

Second, your declaration of `result_array` is incorrect.  Because you're dynamically allocating space for the array, it should be an `int *`.  Also, don't cast the result of `malloc` in C:

```
int *result_array = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```